# What is this property on partial orders called?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Suppose you have some partial order A with the following property: For all $a,b \in A$, whenever a <= b, there are only finitely many $c \in A$ such that $a \leq c \leq b$. What is this property called?

For example, the natural numbers with their usual ordering have this property, but the real numbers do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [locally finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_poset).